# Add ~ (tilde) in an Erlang string

Tags: text, erlang, file-writing

I want to add ~ (tilde) in the string and write this string to a file.

Eg.

```
String = "~Hi~Welcome ~Presenting ~My~Problem~To~you Public ~L.",
ile:write_file(WriteFileName, io_lib:fwrite(String,[])).
```

Error received

```
** Reason for termination == 
** {badarg,[{io_lib,format,
                    ["~Hi~Welcome ~Presenting ~My~Problem~To~you Public ~L.",
                     []],
                    [{file,"io_lib.erl"},{line,168}]},.....]}
```

Any Help Appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two of them:

```
1> io:format("~~~s~~~s~~~n", ["Hello", "World"]).
~Hello~World~
ok
```

From the [io:fwrite/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fwrite-1) documentation:

> **Available control sequences:**
>
> **~**
>
> Character ~ is written.

Comment: Thanks, @Roger!! its little tedious to add string this way, still worthy.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the call to `io_lib:fwrite` there; you can just pass the string to `file:write_file` directly:

```
String = "~Hi~Welcome ~Presenting ~My~Problem~To~you Public ~L.",
file:write_file(WriteFileName, String).
```

Comment: Thanks, @legoscia, how can I add ~n (next line) in the string?? if possible

Comment: You can put `\n` inside the string: `"first line\nsecond line"`

Comment: Thanks, @legoscia!! great solution, +1!! :) worth to be accepted!!